# Inputenc problem in Beamer

Tags: beamer, input-encodings

I need to use Spanish accents in beamer but I get errors when I use it

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amssymb, amsfonts, amsxtra}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}

\title[The Title]{ Códigos}
%\subtitle[The Subtitle]{The Subtitle \\ Based on A Really Important Paper \\ by Some Other Author}
\author[The Author]{}
\institute{UNC - Famaf \\ Córdoba}


\begin{document}


\section{Introducción}
\begin{frame} 
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The accent doesn´t appear or I get errors in compilation, can anyone help me?
I always use the `inputenc` package in other document classes and I have no problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the file with Latin-1 encoding?

Comment: OK, i always use Latin-1 encoding in other projects by default, but is my first time with beamer so i suppuse that would be the same. I set UTf8 and seems to work fine now, thanks

Comment: It doesn't depend on the class, but only on how you save your file on disk.

Comment: Ok, but i dont know why it changed because i save the file as i always do